# Selenium, WebDriver for Chrome Stopping the window opening

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When using the `WebDriver driver` for Chrome a chrome window opens, and navigates to the specified page.

Is there a way to stop the window from opening?

Edit: I am using it to scrape the web page so there is no need for me to see the actual webpage. The desired behaviour would be that the scraping would be done "Silently"?

Comment: Then, what is your desired behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Then what's the point of having the chrone driver?

Comment: Are you looking for the [HtmlUnitDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called a *headless browser*.

You have several options to choose from:

- fake a display and let selenium and a browser think you have a real one. See [`xvfb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).
- use [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) browser
- run your tests against [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) or [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) selenium servers (or have your own one)

See also:

- [Selenium Headless Automated Testing in Ubuntu](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/)
- [Getting Started with GhostDriver & PhantomJs](http://assertselenium.com/2013/03/25/getting-started-with-ghostdriver-phantomjs/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, one question could I just substitute Chrome for PhantomJs? Drivers and all?

Comment: @J4C3N-14 by default it would be with a head; but if used with `xvfb` you can "fake" a headless mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm now "Headless" along with your answer pointing me down the right path and this questions answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122185/how-to-run-ghostdriver-from-java it all ended up being quite painless. Although I had no need to use xvfb to run it headless?

Comment: Also the speed of the scraping has been increased quite dramatically by being headless, side effect of not having to load all the graphics?