# Headless browser not executing properly

Tags: java, selenium, headless-browser

I use selenium webdriver to automate my test-cases.

My objective to execute headless browser using `HtmlUnitDriver` on a sample selenium script. Please find the script mentioned below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Headless 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        //driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

       // WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=k36cVsa6OubI8Aec14bICQ&gws_rd=ssl"); 

        /*WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("sb_ifc0")));
        */
        Thread.sleep(50000);
        System.out.println("URL= "+driver.getCurrentUrl());

        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());     
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
URL= about:blank
Page title is:
```

The output is working fine for `FirefoxDriver()`

Could anyone guide where I went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script not working in HtmlUnitDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848433/script-not-working-in-htmlunitdriver)

Comment: i believe you've already asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848433/script-not-working-in-htmlunitdriver