# Jersey authentication for SSO

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jira

I am currently trying to access Jira REST with Jersey.
The problem is that for our Jira a single sign on is set up.
Authentication with "client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(..." does not work.
If I access Jira via browser and then hardcode the received cookie into Jersey I am able to access Jira REST.

My question would now be how to login with Jersey over SSO.
From what I can see clicking "Login" on the SSO page just sends a POST request with a request body like "username=&password=&login-form-type=pwd".
So I should be able to retrieve a cookie with Jersey the same way I guess...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done with Selenium Ghost Driver.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                "/Path/to/bin/phantomjs");                  
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Afterwards I use the driver to enter username and password, log in, get the new cookie and then use this cookie with Jersey.

Might not be the ideal way but it works.

[How to run ghostdriver with Selenium using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122185/how-to-run-ghostdriver-with-selenium-using-java)