# Hidden HTML elements using Mechanize Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, mechanize, hidden

So I'm writing a Python script that checks Blackboard (school interface site) for updates. But the HTML I receive back from my script is not completely the same as the HTML when viewed in my browser. I'm unsure if this is a cookie issue or what I'm missing.

```
USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

updates = 0  
site = 'http://schoolsite.edu'

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(site)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['j_username'] = USERNAME
browser.form['j_password'] = PASSWORD
browser.submit()

#it brings back an empty form, just submit it.
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.submit()

html_resp = browser.response().read()
```

The HTML in question looks like this  (this is from the script)

```
<span id="badgeTotal" style="visibility: hidden" title="">
<span class="hideoff" id="badgeAXLabel">Activity Updates</span>
<span class="badge" id="badgeTotalCount" title=""></span>
```

What I was expecting it to look like (from Chrome/actual browser)

```
<span id="badgeTotal" style="visibility: visible;" title="">
<span class="hideoff" id="badgeAXLabel">Activity Updates</span>
<span class="badge" id="badgeTotalCount" title="">1</span>
```

What I'm really after is that '1' number in the last line, but I feel like the visibility attribute is holding it back. Note that I get the same cookies from Mechanize that I also get in browser. (not exact same, but same id, name, ect.)

Any thoughts?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure there is *javascript involved* [which mechanize cannot handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript).

An alternative solution here would be to automate a real browser through [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # could also be headless: webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://schoolsite.edu')

# submit a login form
username = driver.find_element_by_name('j_username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('j_password')

username.send_keys(USERNAME)
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

username.submit()

# wait for the badge count to appear
badge_count = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "badgeTotalCount")))

print(badge_count.text)
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Thanks @alecxe. It worked!

I didn't want to deal with Firefox opening and closing, so I used this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370762/how-to-hide-firefox-window-firefox-webdriver). It was good thing you added that comment about PhantomJS.

I also had to add a delay for it to grab the badge count. So the last couple lines look like:
    `badge_count = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "badgeTotalCount")))`
    `sleep(2)`
    `print(badge_count.text)`

I know that's not elegant, but it works.