# Get element from website with python without opening a browser

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write a python script which parses one element from a website and simply prints it.

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this, without `selenium`'s `webdiver`, in order to open a browser which handles the scripts to properly display the website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/pages/landing/home.shtml#!product/910000800509')
content = browser.page_source
print(content[42000:43000])
browser.close()
```

This is just a rough draft which will print the contents, including the element of interest `<span class="prod-price-inner">£13.00</span>`.

How could I get the element of interest without the browser opening, or even without a browser at all?

***edit:*** I've previously tried to use `urllib` or in `bash` `wget`, which both lack the required javascript interpretation.

Comment: I'm planning to create a small Python script.

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it :) I'll post my answer in a bit. Just to make sure I got it right, You need the price element, right ?

Comment: You want to hide the browser? Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370762/how-to-hide-firefox-window-firefox-webdriver/23898148#23898148

Comment: In the meanwhile, you can take a look at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/, to install use `pip install BeautifulSoup4`

Comment: You can only parse that page with a browser. The page doesn't display anything if javascript isn't enabled. Selenium is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers mentioned, this webpage requires javascript to render content, so you can't simply get and process the page with [lxml](http://lxml.de/), [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), or similar library. But there's a much ***simpler*** way to get the information you want.

I noticed that the link you provided fetches data from an internal API in a structured fashion. It appears that the product number is `910000800509` based on the url. If you look at the networking tab in Chrome dev tools (or your brower's equivalent dev tools), you'll see that a GET request is being made to following URL: http://groceries.asda.com/api/items/view?itemid=910000800509.

You can make the request like this with just the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) modules:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://groceries.asda.com/api/items/view?itemid=910000800509'
r = requests.get(url)
price = r.json()['items'][0]['price']

print price
£13.00
```

This also gives you access to lots of other information about the product, since the request returns some JSON with product details.

Comment: Elegant, simplistic and functional!

Comment: I'd like to know how you found the GET request.. Also, this product number `910000456105` doesn't seem to work, I always get price `£0.00`.. from the URL `http://groceries.asda.com/product/canned-lagers/tennents-lager/910000456105`..
other than that, perfect!

Comment: I'd edit my comment but it's too late. It seems like the product is currently not available, thus the price.

Comment: I just checked this other product `910000456105`. It looks like when the product is unavailable, the price shows as £0.00. You can see the previous price at the `wasPrice` attribute with `price = r.json()['items'][0]['wasPrice']`.

Comment: I found the GET request by visiting the url you provided, then I opened dev tools. Then, click on the network tab, and refresh the page. You can see all requests being made here. This might be helpful to you: [http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> How could I get the element of interest without the browser opening,
>   or even without a browser at all?

After inspecting the page you're trying to parse :

http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/pages/landing/home.shtml#!product/910000800509

I realized that it only displays the content if `javascript` is enabled, based on that, you need to use a *real* **browser**.

---

**Conclusion:**

The way to go, if you need to automatize, is:

[selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)