# selenium ! hide and show?

Tags: selenium, browser, bots

how can i show and hide browser in selenium

mean if i click in button b1 it will hide browser and if i click b2 or same b1 button it will show my browser

and if i want to show popup in new tab in selenium with firefox how can i do it??

ex :if i click on page and this page have popup ads i want to open this popup in new tab how can i do it??
if i can't how can i control 2 browser with selenium like select first firefox windows ??
i'm new programmer so i need easy and simple answer :P
(java please)
Regards

Comment: This is not a site for you to ask other people to write code for you. Make an attempt to write the code yourself. If you have problems, post the code, describe the problem, and ask for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370762/how-to-hide-firefox-window-firefox-webdriver