# Closing Firefox windows running in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, window

I am playing with selenium in Python and Firefox windows in headless mode. The problem is that I've created lots of Firefox windows in headless mode using [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828726/7550772), if you ask me.

First of all, I don't understand why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828726/7550772) earned no votes whatsoever, except for my own, even if it seems to work fine. Can someone explain? Maybe I am missing something. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Secondly, unfortunately, I did not close those windows running in headless mode using `driver.close()` in Python code, and there are lots of them. I wonder, how can I close them all now?

The only solution I have found (for `Ubuntu` and `MacOS High Sierra`) is this:

```
ps aux | grep firefox | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

..., which should be run in terminal.

But it not only closes all Firefox windows in headless mode. It literally kills all the processes related to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Search by geckodriver and then kill your gecko processes.

```
netstat -tlp | egrep '(firefo|vnc|gecko)'
```

It comes something like this:

```
0      0 localhost:9090          *:*                     LISTEN      11970/geckodriver
```

Comment: Currently I don't have access to `Ubuntu`. I am trying this on `MacOS High Sierra`, and it is not working there. My "solution", however, works for both `Ubuntu` and `MacOS High Sierra`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am trying it out in Ubuntu. I am not sure how `egrep` works. Could you explain? `netstat -tlp | grep firefox` gives me info about the processes in headless mode, indeed. How did you find it out? And also, I don't know how to extract the PID from the line :(

Comment: egrep treats the pattern as a regular expression. Also, netstat -tlp | egrep '(firefo|chro|gecko)' | awk '/:* */ {split($NF,a,"/"); print a[2],a[1]}' .... this can help you extract the PID.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried the accepted answer, it killed some visible firefox windows as well. Using `htop`, I found that all firefox windows running in headless mode using python selenium corresponded to the command `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox --marionette --headless -foreground -no-remote -profile <tmp file>`.
So, using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50573) on Unix stack exchange, I came up with:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "firefox --marionette -headless" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done`
```