# The right way to run Firefox in headless mode (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-headless

I was wondering how to run hidden Firefox window when testing a page in Selenium and came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50828726/7550772). It says that I can run Firefox in headless mode like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.close()
```

But it earned no votes whatsoever. It seems like people think it is a wrong answer. ***Why?***

Also, in official documentation I found that it can be done like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.close()
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two ways?

Comment: I'd say following the official documentation is a good bet on the 'right way' to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solutions sets an environment variable on your computer, i.e. changing your platform. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)

> If the platform supports the putenv() function, this mapping may be
>   used to modify the environment

It will work only if your platform supports [putenv()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.putenv)

> Availability: most flavors of Unix, Windows.

The second solution sets the `webdriver` instance with some options, without changing your platform.