# How to get data using javascript in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to use javascript to get the data in a webpage.

In the first image, there is a highlighted link for you to click.

After that, you will get the webpage in the second image.

The desired data is highlighted.

I can get the data using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

The data in the second image is retrieved using javascript from somewhere before displaying to us.

How to get the data using javascript?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

fig1_url = r'https://huangshigongyuanzy.fang.com/'
fig2_url = r'https://huangshigongyuanzy.fang.com/house/2612049076/fangjia.htm'

headers = {'user-agent':r'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(fig2_url, headers=headers)
resp.encoding='GB18030'

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
for i in soup.find('div', {'id': 'priceListOpen'}).findAll('tr'):
  for j in i.findAll('td'):
    print(j.text+'|',end = ' ')
  print('\n' + '-'*50)
```

You can run the snippet [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz8kk.png).
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include the code in your question itself.

Comment: I feel, the page is rendered using Javascript. Which I would recommend to handle with headless browser (Chrome/ PhantomJS). You may follow the tutorials from here - https://realpython.com/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/

Comment: `Selenium` requires `fig2_url`, which may be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the `fig2_url` and I found that this page was using **server rendering**. So, you have to use some tools to craw the data from it.

This [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) provided us with a perfect tutorial.

When you craw a website, first thing to look for are terms of use. Some Site explicitly address the possibility of using their website with scraping APIs. Always be sure to take a look at these before.

Comment: Thank you, vuluu. I will take a look on it. Any python tools?

Comment: I am new to Scrapy and javascript. Can you tell me how to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using Selenium webdriver? I was looking into it for another project and it looked promising. It actually invokes your browser, so it should do the javascript for you (I think):

```
from selenium import webdriver
fig2_url = r'https://huangshigongyuanzy.fang.com/house/2612049076/fangjia.htm'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(fig2_url)
driver.page_source.encode('GB18030')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
for i in soup.find('div', {'id': 'priceListOpen'}).findAll('tr'):
  for j in i.findAll('td'):
    print(j.text+'|',end = ' ')
  print('\n' + '-'*50)
```

Seems to work.

Caveats:

1. It relies on Mozilla [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), on github.
2. You can't fake the headers, as with requests; but then, since it's actually opening using Firefox, you probably don't need to.
3. At least with the above code, it opens a browser and geckodrive window; there may be some way to suppress that, but I haven't looked into it. This was just a bare-bones attempt. [edit: the question [How to hide Firefox window (Selenium WebDriver)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370762/how-to-hide-firefox-window-selenium-webdriver/23898148#23898148) describes how to get around this with PhantomJS. I haven't tried it.]

Comment: Thanks codingatty. `Selenium` cannot actually solve my problem as `fig2_url` may be disabled. I want to pass some parameters to run the javascript and get the results.