# Can we show/hide selenium browser on demand

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I know we can create headless browser. But my question here is can we make it switch between Visible and Invisible mode.

So if i want to show something i do something like:

```
driver.Visible=true;
```

and they see it and after that i can do :

```
driver.Visible=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the driver visible for some time and not for some time. One way is, you can minimize your driver whenever you don't require.

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370762/how-to-hide-firefox-window-selenium-webdriver)